# A class is a constructor in one file but not in other

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, discord

Hello there I've got an interesting question.
I'm having a class that meant to create a channel instance in Discord.
And I'm having the Message constructor which has

```
this.channel = new GuildChannel(client, client.channels.get(this.channelID));
```

This works inside **Message Structure** only.
When I'm coming to use GuildChannel constructor in other file (Same folder)
I'm getting the next error. `TypeError: GuildChannel is not a constructor`

Related code:
[hastebin because I cannot post more than 2 links](https://hastebin.com/kuzapiyohi.rb)

Here are the hastebin links:
1) Message Structure 
https://github.com/TheOnlyArtz/ArtzyCord/blob/master/Models/Message.js#L21

2) Invite Structure (when the error happens)
https://github.com/TheOnlyArtz/ArtzyCord/blob/master/Models/Invite.js#L10

3) GuildChannel Structure (the error)
https://github.com/TheOnlyArtz/ArtzyCord/blob/master/Models/GuildChannel.js

Comment: Are you accidentally setting GuildChannel to another object or type?

Comment: Clearly I'm not. You can see this inside the code
https://hastebin.com/kuzapiyohi.rb

Comment: Rather than posting 3 links to code, Please include a relevant  [Minimum Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *within the body of the question*.  Links may become unreachable, invalidating the question.  Also, it's *much* easier to help if we don't have to jump around the web to find out your question.  Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then `edit` your question so we may effectively help.

Comment: I don't know how to describe it else than that other than saying:
Imagine you have a class.
and you're trying to invoke this class from 2 files

In one file the class will invoke normally and in the other file it will throw an error, like `<name> is not a constructor`
(And yes, I'm requiring them the same way)

Comment: Why are you requiring in GuildChannel 2 different ways?

Comment: Because it didn't work with `path` module so I've tried the normal way.

(Which didn't work too)

Comment: Can you try in the file that fails to move the require to the first line of the code and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Same thing, that is so strange.

Comment: UPDATE: I've got it to work only when doing
`this.GuildChannel = require("./GuildChannel.js")`
so weird!!!!\